# Phalcon sample application Vokuro: CSRF validation failed?

Tags: php, phalcon

When I try the Phalcon sample application 'Vokuro', I get a `CSRF validation failed` error when I try to create an account.

I have no idea why that's happening or even what CSRF is really about, I'm just trying out this sample.

Did anybody get this sample working with Phalcon 2.0.8 on PHP 5.6.14 / Windows XAMPP?

Comment: The `CSRF validation failed` message comes from [here](https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro/blob/master/app/forms/SignUpForm.php#L102).The CSRF check in the form basically checks if the form that is being submitted is actually the form that you generated on your page.

Comment: Maybe the Security service isn't setup correctly. Look at the [Phalcon docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-protection) on how to "Setting up the component"